# Adjust UIScrollView's contentSize with an embedded UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScroll view which contains only one subview. The subview called `contentView`is an UIView. Here is what I did in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

// pin all edges to the edges of the superview (self.view)
self.scrollView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
  make.edges.equalTo(self.view)
}

// create contentView
self.contentView = UIView()
self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.scrollView.addSubview(self.contentView)

// pin the edges of the contentView to the scrollView
self.contentView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
  make.edges.equalTo(self.scrollView) 
}

let myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 20, 300))
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.contentView.addSubview(myView)
```

The result is this:

[image]

There is ne red contentView as shown in the previous screen shot.

Next, I tried to adjust the size of the contenView in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
let newSize: CGSize = self.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
println("newSize: \(newSize)")
```

The result is:

```
newSize: (0.0, 0.0)
```

**How can I either setup the correct size of the contentView or set the correct size of the UIScrollView's contentSize?**

Comment: did you figure this out? Curious to know what you did...

Comment: You have to pin the bottom edge of the green view to the bottom of the contentView.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the `var contentSize: CGSize` of the UIScrollView? The documentation says

> **Discussion**
>  The unit of size is points. The default size is CGSizeZero.

If you don't know the size of the content view, then I would recommend setting

```
scrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

and

```
scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

for good measure.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the size of the content it is determined by the views inside the contentView.